# Does the momentum operator applied to a position state vanish?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, momentum, fourier-transform

In quantum mechanics we have
\begin{equation*}
\langle x|p\rangle=C\exp\left(\frac{ipx}{\hbar}\right)
\end{equation*}
where $C$ is a normalization constant.

It follows that
\begin{equation*}
-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigl(\langle x|p\rangle\bigr)
=-i\hbar C\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\exp\left(\frac{ipx}{\hbar}\right)
=p\langle x|p\rangle
\tag{1}
\end{equation*}

However by the product rule we can also write
\begin{equation*}
-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigl(\langle x|p\rangle\bigr)
=-i\hbar
\left[
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\langle x|\right)|p\rangle
+\langle x|\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|p\rangle\right)
\right]
\tag{1.1}
\end{equation*}

Rewrite as
\begin{equation*}
-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigl(\langle x|p\rangle\bigr)
=-i\hbar\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\langle x|\right)
|p\rangle
+p\langle x|p\rangle
\tag{2}
\end{equation*}

Then by equivalence of (1) and (2) we have
\begin{equation*}
-i\hbar\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\langle x|\right)
|p\rangle=0
\tag{3}
\end{equation*}

Is this correct?

EDIT: No, it is not correct.
The mistake is in equation (2).
As pointed out in the accepted answer,
the correct form of (2) is
\begin{equation*}
-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigl(\langle x|p\rangle\bigr)
=-i\hbar\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\langle x|\right)
|p\rangle
\tag{2'}
\end{equation*}
because
\begin{equation*}
\langle x|\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|p\rangle\right)=0
\end{equation*}

It follows from (2') that
\begin{equation*}
-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigl(\langle x|p\rangle\bigr)
=p\langle x|p\rangle
\end{equation*}
which is equivalent to equation (1) as required.

Comment: Your notation is *very* confusing (which may be the cause of your trouble).

Comment: Careful when taking the derivative of a ket as you wrote it: this is like writing $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\hat x$, which in itself makes no sense.  After all, $\vert x\rangle$ is a unit vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notations are confusing and not at all consistent with the conventional Dirac notation :

- an operator $\hat {\mathcal O}$ should be applied to a ket $|\psi\rangle$,  forming an expression like $\hat{\mathcal O}|\psi\rangle$. For example, the fact that $|p\rangle$ is an eigenvector of the operator $\hat p$ is written :
  \begin{equation}
  \hat p |p\rangle = p|p\rangle\tag{1}\end{equation}
- $|x\rangle$ and $|p\rangle$ are ket-valued functions of $x$ and $p$ respectively. In other words for each value of $x$ there is a ket $|x\rangle$ representing a particle at the position $x$. Consequently, by taking the hermitian product $\langle x|p\rangle$, we obtain a complex-valued function of $x$ and $p$, and specifically :
  $$\langle x|p\rangle = C\exp\left(\frac{ipx}{\hbar}\right) \tag 2$$
- the operator $\hat p$ is $-i\hbar \partial_x$ *in the position representation*. This can be written in several different ways, one of which is that for any ket $|\psi\rangle$, we have :
  $$\langle x |\hat p|\psi\rangle = -i\hbar \partial_x (\langle x|\psi\rangle)
  \tag 3$$
  Everything makes sense in the RHS, as $\langle x|\psi\rangle$ is a complex-valued function which we can differentiate easily.

Now, it might seem that equations $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$ allow us to compute $\langle x |\hat p|p\rangle$ in two different ways, so we might wan to check that everything is consistent. On one hand we have :
$$\langle x |\hat p|p\rangle = \langle x |\big( p|p\rangle\big) = p\langle x |p\rangle$$
while on the other hand we have :
\begin{align}
\langle x |\hat p|p\rangle &= -i\hbar \partial_x ( \langle x |p\rangle) \\
&= -i\hbar \Big[ \partial_x \big(\langle x|\big) |p\rangle + \langle x| \partial_x \big(|p\rangle\big)\Big]
\end{align}
Here, we have applied the product rule to the two ket-valued functions $|x\rangle $ and $|p\rangle$. However, $|p\rangle$ does not depend on $x$, so its derivative with respect to $x$ vanishes and we are left with :
$$  \langle x |\hat p|p\rangle = -i\hbar  \partial_x \big(\langle x|\big) |p\rangle \tag 4$$

This equation holds for any value of $p$. As the kets $|p\rangle$ form a basis of the Hilbert space, equation $(4)$ is equivalent to  :
$$\langle x |\hat p = -i\hbar  \partial_x \big(\langle x|\big)  $$
or, taking the hermitian conjugate, to :
$$\hat p |x\rangle  = i\hbar \partial_x |x\rangle \tag{4'}$$
We see that what we are left is just an equivalent way of writing down $\hat p $ in the position representation.

Answer (score 2):

$i\hbar\,\partial/\partial x$ is the momentum operator in the position representation. It is not the momentum operator that acts in the Hilbert space of abstract kets like $|p\rangle$, so your eq. $(2)$ doesn't follow. There is simply no way to make sense of such an expression.

Rather, starting from $\hat{p}|p\rangle=p|p\rangle$, we have that

\begin{align*}
\hat{p}|p\rangle=p\int{\rm d}x\,e^{ipx/\hbar}|x\rangle=\int{\rm d}x\,|x\rangle\left(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)e^{ipx/\hbar},
\end{align*}
so, from $e^{ipx/\hbar}=\langle x|p\rangle$, it follows that $$\hat{p}=\int{\rm d}x\,|x\rangle\left(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\langle x|$$

Comment: @TheLittleDogLaughed my suggestion would be to go back to the definition of the derivative: ${\rm d}f/{\rm d}x=\lim_{h\to 0}(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$. Can you recover the product rule when the "product" is $f(x)=\langle x|p\rangle$? (spoiler: no, you cannot, because it is not a product of functions of $x$).

Comment: I believe you are technically out by a factor of $1/\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}$ in converting $\langle x\vert p\rangle$ to the exponential.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I always forget which factors go where so you could very well be correct. I think in this case if you choose $\langle p|p^\prime\rangle=2\pi\hbar\,\delta(p-p^\prime)$ then it comes out as I wrote, while yours corresponds to the choice $\langle p|p^\prime\rangle=\delta(p-p^\prime)$.

Comment: The natural choice is $\langle x\vert p\rangle=e^{ipx/\hbar}/\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}$ so that $\langle p\vert x\rangle=\langle x\vert p\rangle^*$ so you never have to worry about $2\pi$ factors as you do.